# AWS limit number of EC2s created by user

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to find a way to make upper limit number of created EC2s in specific region in AWS.

any one can help ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limits on the number of Amazon EC2 instances that can be launched by an **account** in a given **region**. However, it is *not possible* to limit the number of instances launched by a *specific user*.

Permissions can be assigned to users to determine whether or not they are permitted to launch instances (and to further restrict what instances they can launch, and where). However, **there is no ability to limit the quantity of instances launched by a specific user**.

If this is a requirement, then you will need to write your own "in-between" app that checks per-user limits and then launches the instance(s) on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

AWS applies limits based on various factors. The default limits are dependent on your instance type. You can find more info here: [How many instances can I run in Amazon EC2?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2)

If you need to increase those limits you will need to contact AWS customer support with the request, which they will evaluate. You can find instructions for requesting a service limit increase here: [AWS Service Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)